# How to use SQL code to select the latest ID that is not in order (Even though I have sort it)

Tags: mysql, sql, dom, select, xampp

[So it is a picture that show my ID that is in order if we assume **S2** is bigger **S10**. The order of my ID is **S1, S10, S11, S12, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6, S7, S8, S9**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vci0G.png)

I wrote my SQL code like this and the latest ID it return is **S9**
Just keep in mind that I want the alphabet beside the number.
So which SQL code allow me to select the latest ID that is **S12** ? PLS help me.

```
SELECT IdSoalan FROM SOALAN ORDER BY IdSoalan DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: There needs to exist a column which describes which ID comes first or last.  SQL tables themselves have no notion of "order."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT IdSoalan FROM SOALAN ORDER BY LENGTH(IdSoalan) DESC, IdSoalan DESC LIMIT 1
```

It sorts by length of the column in a descending order and then by the value in a descending order and limits the result to 1. It's called natural sorting in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `order by` cause this is because your `IdSoalan` is a alphanumeric data.
You shouldn't use this type of data as typical `ID` but try this :

```
ORDER BY LENGTH(IdSoalan), IdSoalan
```

this should make your data order like this :
S1 - S9 then S10 - S12 and go on.
for descending form just put `desc` on both.

```
ORDER BY LENGTH(IdSoalan) DESC, IdSoalan DESC
```

Comment: use the same query you got and just change the `order by` clause.

Comment: i try to add DESC LIMIT 1 at the back of your code but still return S9

Comment: `SELECT IdSoalan FROM SOALAN ORDER BY LENGTH(IdSoalan) DESC, IdSoalan DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: make sure you got both `desc`

Comment: @SzeYuSim  kinda bruh for me cause this two answer is exactly same but glad OP solve it anyways.